# Access current my jquery plugin instances and variables inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new in creating jquery plugin, I created It with knockout binding to be more dynamic, and it work fine, but I need to access a knockout viewmodel of an instance applied on an HTML element, How can I do that?

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.CFITGrid = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var defaultOpthions = {
            // here default options values
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaultOpthions, options);

        function CFITGridViewModel() {
            // class I will use it
        }

        var CFITGridViewModelObject = new CFITGridViewModel(); // Variable I need to access
        // do somthing
    });
}})(jQuery);
//In the page
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Datadiv").CFITGrid({
    DefaultLoadDataUrl: "api/apiUserInfo/GetList?pageNumber=" + 1,
    DefaultPropertiesName: ["FirstNme", "LastName", "UserName"],
});
// I need to access the instance of the plugin and variable which inside it here
});
```

Comment: I need to access created instance of CFITGrid and its variable after applying it

Comment: You have a lot of code in your question, most of it is probably irrelevant to the actual problem. Could you please updte your question, strip all the unneeded bits, and perhaps show us what you've tried so far so the problem becomes more apparent/specific? Perhaps turning it into a [repro](http://sscce.org) would help as well.

Comment: you are right, I did,
thanks Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy to access to KO viewModel if you have acces to any of the bound elements (i.e. you don't need to be on the root of the binding).

If you have the root of the binding, this will return the bound viewmodel:

```
ko.dataFor(rootElement);
```

If your viewmodel is flat (i.e. it doesn't contain sub-objects or collections) you can do exactly the same to access the bound view model from any of the inner dom objects. But, if your viewmodel is hierarchical, you should use `ko.contextFor(someElement)`, that will give you access to the full [context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), i.e. `$data`, `$parent`, `$parents`, `$root`...

See this knockout documentation: [Using unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)

Comment: Thanks Mr JotaBe, I got it, but I still need to access another variable which is not bound view model, like var var1 = []; Can I do this?

Comment: Where is taht variable defined? It's not a good idea to get something "from over there". You should find a way to pass it in a clear, direct way. Why don't you open another question with some sample code so that I can find a solution for you?